# I am looking at the relationship between Age ($x$) and Total Length ($y$) of fish and try to see if there are differences depending on the pedigree

Tags: r, regression, interaction, lm

I want to know if there is difference in slope between the two Origins `H` and `W` (pedigree), but I am not sure which of those two models is the best to answer my question.

````
mod6 <- lm(TL ~ Age_day*factor(Origin), data=juve, subset=((Origin=="H")|(Origin=="W")))
summary(mod6)

#Call:
#lm(formula = TL ~ Age_day * factor(Origin), data = juve, subset = ((Origin == "H") | (Origin == "W")))

#Residuals:
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#-11.5004  -2.5358   0.5541   2.4845  13.0370 

#Coefficients:
#                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)              -9.4353     5.6035  -1.684   0.0942 .  
#Age_day                   0.6924     0.1254   5.520 1.37e-07 ***
#factor(Origin)W          17.2204     7.1878   2.396   0.0178 *  
#Age_day:factor(Origin)W  -0.3969     0.1603  -2.477   0.0143 *  
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#Residual standard error: 4.062 on 157 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.2008,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.1855 
#F-statistic: 13.15 on 3 and 157 DF,  p-value: 1.055e-07

mod7 <- lm(TL ~ Age_day+ Origin, data=juve, subset=((Origin=="H")|(Origin=="W")))
summary(mod7)

#Call:
#lm(formula = TL ~ Age_day + Origin, data = juve, subset = ((Origin =="H") | (Origin == "W")))

#Residuals:
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#-10.6432  -2.2945   0.3113   2.3539  12.4127 

#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  1.37765    3.56926   0.386    0.700    
#Age_day      0.44928    0.07934   5.663 6.86e-08 ***
#OriginW     -0.50523    0.67611  -0.747    0.456    
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#Residual standard error: 4.127 on 158 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.1696,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.159 
#F-statistic: 16.13 on 2 and 158 DF,  p-value: 4.223e-07
```
````

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there is difference in slope between the two Origins H and W (pedigree)

For this you need to fit a model that includes the interaction between the two variables. The interaction estimate will answer this question.

So, the first model is the best one. It also has better model fit (higher adjusted $R^2$)

Comment: @Mathilde does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer, and if not, please let us know why ?